# HTML not formatting correctly using wp_editor()

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

#### Wordpress WYSIWYG Editor doesn't format the *saved* HTML output correctly

I have a screenshot which explains exactly what's going on, and I'll post my code snippets too.

[image: Screenshot Here]

I'm making a wordpress plugin that adds text that is edited in the WYSIWYG editor that is called in on my custom settings page. I've got it to post the saved input to where I want it to go (via editing the themes template file though, not what I really wanted, but it's working) but it outputs the saved text with none of the formatting that was chosen in the WYSIWYG via my plugin page.

I've been doing some reading, and I'm thinking it might be something to do with the `esc_html` perhaps? I'm really not too sure.

This snippet, is my **actual WordPress plugin:**

```
<?php
/*/
Plugin Name: Custom Text Adder
Plugin URI: N/A
Description: Demonstrates how rubbish I am at pretty much everything I want to do
Version: 101
Author: JD
Author URI: N/A
/*/


// create custom plugin settings menu
add_action('admin_menu', 'custom_create_menu');


// Add Font-Size to WYSIWYG Editor
function wp_editor_fontsize_filter( $options ) {
    array_shift( $options );
    array_unshift( $options, 'fontsizeselect');
    array_unshift( $options, 'formatselect');
    return $options;
}
add_filter('mce_buttons_2', 'wp_editor_fontsize_filter');



function custom_create_menu() {

    //create new top-level menu
    add_menu_page('Custom Plugin Settings', 'Custom Settings', 'administrator', __FILE__, 'custom_settings_page',plugins_url('/img/icon.png', __FILE__));

    //call register settings function
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_mysettings' );
}


function register_mysettings() {
    //register our settings
    register_setting( 'custom-settings-group', 'new_option_name' );
    register_setting( 'custom-settings-group', 'some_other_option' );
    register_setting( 'custom-settings-group', 'option_etc' );
    register_setting( 'custom-settings-group', 'font_size' );
    register_setting( 'custom-settings-group', 'post_text' );
}

function custom_settings_page() {
?>
<div class="wrap">
<h2>Custom Text</h2>

<?php?>

<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields( 'custom-settings-group' ); ?>



    <table class="form-table">

        <?php /* Bring the editor onto the page */

wp_editor( '', 'post_text', $settings = array() );



/**
 * 4.
 * Custom buttons for the editor.
 * This is a list separated with a comma after each feature
 * eg. link, unlink, bold, ...
 */

$settings = array(
    'textarea_name' => 'post_text',
    'media_buttons' => true,
    'tinymce' => array(
        'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'formatselect,|,bold,italic,underline,|,' .
            'bullist,blockquote,|,justifyleft,justifycenter' .
            ',justifyright,justifyfull,|,link,unlink,|' .
            ',spellchecker,wp_fullscreen,wp_adv'
    )
);

submit_button( 'Save everything', 'primary', 'submit' ); ?>
</form>
</div>
```

And this one, is where the text is being posted to in the themes **home.php template file**:

```
<?php if ( get_option('chameleon_quote') == 'on' ) { ?>
    <div id="category-name"> 
        <div id="category-inner">

            <div><?php print esc_html(get_option('post_text')); ?></div>
        <?php if ( get_option('post_text') <> '' ) { ?>
            <h3><?php echo esc_html(get_option('post_text')); ?></h3>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ( get_option('chameleon_quote_two') <> '' ) { ?>
            <p><?php echo esc_html(get_option('chameleon_quote_two')); ?></p>
        <?php } ?>  
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end .category-name -->
<?php } ?>
```

The `('post_text')` parts are my doing. As you can see I basically copied the bottom function.

Comment: what happens if you do not esc_html?  just straight echo the information.

Comment: I LOVE YOU! 

Bloody genius! I can't believe I never thought to even try that haha. You are a god-send today! Thank you so much Robert!

Comment: Not a problem at all.  Just remember esc_html converts all characters in the text to readable form so that you can display the code :) by escaping the html characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try not using the esc_html

```
<?php if ( get_option('chameleon_quote') == 'on' ) { ?>
    <div id="category-name"> 
        <div id="category-inner">

            <div><?php print get_option('post_text'); ?></div>
        <?php if ( get_option('post_text') <> '' ) { ?>
            <h3><?php echo get_option('post_text'); ?></h3>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ( get_option('chameleon_quote_two') <> '' ) { ?>
            <p><?php echo get_option('chameleon_quote_two'); ?></p>
        <?php } ?>  
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end .category-name -->
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I do have one more question though and do apologise, is there any way I can have my WYSIWYG saved output be posted where it is already, but without having to put anything in the source code of the template file?

That's something that has been bugging me for a while, as it pretty much makes my plugin not really a proper plugin. 

Thanks again though, for your simple, yet massively happiness giving answer!

Comment: Could you clarify your question please?  Like directly inject the code based on the type of page it is or post without having to edit the source theme files?

Comment: Sorry:

I want to be able to have my plugin inject the saved input that is entered in the custom settings page wYSIWYG into that theme template file `home.php` but without having to edit the template file itself. So I can say, zip the plugin up, send it to a friend who is using that theme, and then they can just edit the text in the plugin settings without having to edit the `home.php` file themselves to include that piece of code in your answer above. 

I hope thats a bit more concise!

Thank you for helping too, this issue has been really troublesome. :)

Comment: Typically for a plugin design it would be better to not have it directly edit the theme since once the theme gets updated or changed, it will either add redundant code or other issues.  Personally I would either do some type of shortcode to display the information manually or if you want to automatically have it add the information would be by using a add_filter() to directly add information based on conditions http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content or http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter might help you

Comment: I was going in that direction at the start of the plugin, and couldn't seem to find the filter to add my code to that specific area of the website. I was trying `the_content()` and others, and it was posting the output, but at the end of posts, or the end of every post and things like that. 

I suppose that my main issue, is finding out the right filter to use to get it to post to that specific area of the website. 

Again, thank you so much for your advice, I wish there was a way I could just click "Add Rep"!

Comment: lol thanks for the comment.  There are two methods you can do this.  the simple method is to add it to the wp_footer but that may have other information and could have some issues with the formatting but its worth a shot (and make sure to check if it is a post based on is_single()).  The second option is to add_filter('the_content','function') and add $content = $content . get_options() and replace what is being sent out.  here is a reference that may help you get a better idea on how this can be done http://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-content-to-bottom-of-single-posts-using-functionsphp

Comment: Also one of the answers in this might be exactly what you are looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164789/wordpress-custom-field-output-after-the-content